# SQL Case - how to order by another field ASC

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a SQL query that sorts a table for a local restaurant into categories, but after that I would like to sort alphabetically by title. The end result should sort the categories, and then the content is sorted alphabetically by the title field (like "ORDER BY category, title ASC", only the category gets sorted by case).

My query is

```
SELECT *
FROM menu
ORDER BY CASE WHEN category = 'Appetizers' THEN 1
              WHEN category = 'Entrees' THEN 2
              WHEN category = 'Desserts' THEN 3
          WHEN category = 'Beverages' THEN 4
          END
```

I tried adding ", title ASC" to each line, and after the END but it came up as an error. Can this be done at all?

Comment: *but it came up as an error* this needs clarity.

Comment: Add `, title` after `ORDER BY CASE ... END`. Note that you can't sort for category and title at the same time, you need to decide which of the two has priority on the other.

Comment: I would add `, title ASC` right after `END`.

Comment: Thanks both of you, that worked! I did try that but typed something wrong I guess

Comment: @stu I was building the query in Navicat, and it did not give me any error code, it just said the query would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves like any other `ORDER` sorting

first it will sort by the `CASE` and then every entry with the same category by title

```
SELECT *
FROM menu
ORDER BY CASE WHEN category = 'Appetizers' THEN 1
              WHEN category = 'Entrees' THEN 2
              WHEN category = 'Desserts' THEN 3
          WHEN category = 'Beverages' THEN 4
          ELSE 5
          END ASC, title ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add title in the `ORDER BY` clause after the `CASE` expression.This will sort the data by category based on the CASE and then the title within each category group.

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM menu
ORDER BY CASE WHEN category = 'Appetizers' THEN 1
          WHEN category = 'Entrees' THEN 2
          WHEN category = 'Desserts' THEN 3
      WHEN category = 'Beverages' THEN 4
      END, title;
```